# Remove element, then iterate and combine elements in a list python

Tags: python, list

Let say I have a list like this with `n` elements:

```
myList = ['cr','cd','cs','sp','sd','op','ol','fs','th','ag','ng','rt','bp']
```

I want to remove one element in the list every time while iterating then combine iteratively the other elements in my list to have an output like this:

```
# removing the first element, we would have:
['cd']
['cd', 'cs']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt', 'bp']

# Then removing the second element, we would have:

['cr']
['cr', 'cs']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt', 'bp']

# Removing ith element:
........
```

I have tried like this removing manually one element each time:

```
# 2nd element is removed
myList = ['cr','cs','sp','sd','op','ol','fs','th','ag','ng','rt','bp']
for i in range(1, len(myList) + 1): 
    input_f = myList[:i]
    print(input_f)
```

and get this result:

```
['cr']
['cr', 'cs']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt', 'bp']
```

This puts me one step closer but I can not figure out how to to handle the rest automatically.
Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: The algorithm you describe changes it input. This is *not* needed to get the desired output, and in fact it is easier not to. Do you require modification?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The solution I have now is to remove the element in the list every time before taking it as input. For a list with not many elements, it's fine - but for a list with many elements, it's complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is quite close. You can take two list slices and combine them together to get the desired result at each iteration.

You can use nested loops to achieve the result you want for each removal of a list element.

The outer loop should iterate over the full range of the list.

The inner loop should iterate over the length of the modified list. Each iteration would print the first `j` elements out.

```
myList = ['cr','cd','cs','sp','sd','op','ol','fs','th','ag','ng','rt','bp']

for i in range(len(myList)):
    # these slices skip the i'th element at each iteration
    listSlice = myList[:i] + myList[i + 1:]

    for j in range(1, len(listSlice) + 1):
        print(listSlice[:j])
```

The output with your shown example would look like this:

```
['cd']
['cd', 'cs']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt']
['cd', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt', 'bp']
['cr']
['cr', 'cs']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt']
['cr', 'cs', 'sp', 'sd', 'op', 'ol', 'fs', 'th', 'ag', 'ng', 'rt', 'bp']
...
```

Comment: This works for a list with 3 elements, but over 3 elements, it's not.

Comment: @dnz It should work for any number of elements, assuming you follow the same pattern as shown in your original example. Is there some other output you expect for longer lists? If so, please edit your question to include the desired behavior.

Comment: @costapas With a list like that:

`li = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']` 
Assuming the 'f' element is removed, the expected output, should be like:

`['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
`

Comment: That seems to be a mismatch with your original input/output, in which case none of the answers here satisfy that output.

Comment: @costapas the answers helped, from their results I was able to iterate and combine. I did it in 2 steps then to get my final output.

Comment: your solution is pretty good but your returned lists missed the last element, 'bp', every time.

Comment: @dnz good catch, didn't pick up on that since the lists were so long, simple fencepost error, fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

```
myList = ['a','b','c']

for index,elem in enumerate(myList):
    myList.pop(index)
    print(myList)
    myList.insert(index,elem)
```

Comment: I like it. Simple, and for a quadratic time one it's fast.

Comment: I was stumbling in this area for 20 minutes—you're fantastic bru.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and solve it using list comprehension in your for loop:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
for i in a:
  print([[x for x in a if x != i][0]])
  print([x for x in a if x != i])
```

This outputs:

```
['b']
['b', 'c']
['a']
['a', 'c']
['a']
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: This might fail if there are duplicates.

Comment: Yes, but OP also didn't state the desired behavior for duplicates. I was thinking of going for something with `set()` after the list comprehension, but if OP updates, I'll update my answer too.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "might".

Comment: Oh, haha, reading your second sentence, I see we mean duplicates a bit differently. The possible issue I meant is that for example for `['a','b','a']`, you'd remove *two* elements and produce `['b']`.

Comment: Hmm you are right, yeah, it's a good point. I guess it would require coming up with a more general solution for these cases. Hopefully OP doesn't need them! lol

Comment: @CeliusStingher This works for a list with 3 elements, but over 3 elements, it doesn't.

Comment: Could you please then update your question to address the issue? Because if it's 4 elements (`'a','b','c','d'`) what is the expected output? A permutation? A single element followed by 2 and 3?